# Как удалить дубликаты и запроса MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос

```
SELECT SUM(qty) as grandTotal, datem,GROUP_CONCAT(machine ORDER BY machine SEPARATOR ' , ') AS machines,  sorter as sort FROM metric WHERE datem BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' GROUP BY sorter
```

Всё работает отлично, но поле `machines` дублирует записи т е выводит вот такой результат
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А хотелось бы чтоб он убирал дублирующие записи. Пробовал так

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(qty) as grandTotal, datem,GROUP_CONCAT(machine ORDER BY machine SEPARATOR ' , ') AS machines,  sorter as sort FROM metric WHERE datem BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' GROUP BY sorter
```

Все равно вытаскивает дублирующие ответы. Как быть ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083499/mysql-distinct-on-a-group-concat

Comment: Благодарю, andreymal